# Possible to work with vs2008 project files in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I would like to start using vs 2010 for the IDE benefits. The problem is the rest of my team consider it "a beta" which it is. And right now we're waiting for the RTM to release.

Is it possible for me to use VS2010 to open and edit VS2008 projects and solutions, but have them saved back to vs2008? Are there any pitfalls in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. When you open a VS2008 solution in VS2010, then the familiar project conversion dialog will always appear. At most, you can instruct the project converter wizard to save a backup of your original solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not 'sanctioned', but I've heard that you can have luck just changing the "ToolsVersion" at the top of the .proj file to 4.0, and then it works with both.  VS2010 will use it (that's what it expects), and VS2008 will warn that this is an unknown tools version and just revert to the 3.5 behavior.  So that's a potential use-at-your-own-risk strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Overheard on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/4345a151-d288-48d6-b7c7-a7c598d0f85e):

```
1. Open your VS 2010 .sln in notepad.

It should look something like this:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010 Project("{FAE04EC0-3 ...... ...........................

2. Change the Version 11.0 to Version 10.0 and Visual Studio 2010 to 2008

3. Save the file.

4. Open in vs 2008 all projects should load, compile etc.
```

Disclaimer, I haven't verified this. But I have seen the same technique [described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/4345a151-d288-48d6-b7c7-a7c598d0f85e) as well.